# Getting text from html table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement some edit/update functionality in my project and I am having hard time accessing the td's in the pricture below.
Firstly, I am not sure if having a class for each `<td>` is a good idea at all, but this is how I did it.
On each row I have an edit button, which, when pressed is supposed to get the info for the specific row. With my code this works only for the first row.

I have the following structure in the dom :

[image]

I tried to access the `<td>` elements in this way :

```
$('#lblEditDeleteProducts .brandDom').eq(0).text();
```

But the problem is that this always gets the text from the first row and I have many rows.

I also tried this code, which didn't work :

```
$(this).closest('.nameDom').text()
```

Comment: Try this maybe:

$('#lblEditDeleteProducts .brandDom').eq(1).text();

Comment: Is the edit button in a table cell in the same row?

Comment: where is your edit button?

Comment: I have a button on each row.

Comment: @AyaSalama the button is in the <th> tags!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the edit button isn't a child of the column with class `nameDom` then [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) won't find anything. Try getting the parent `tr` and then searching from there: `$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text()`

Answer (score 1):

The selector is completly wrong:

```
var i = 1;
$('#lblEditDeleteProducts tr').eq(i).find('.brandDom').text();
```

Select firstly `#lblEditDeleteProducts tr` to detect the parent of all elements then find your child using `.find()`. Using the `.eq()` make you select the x-index of the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me(from the post above).

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text()
```